# Does the 2011 iMac have SATA 3 support?

Tags: imac, ssd, sata

I'm excited about the iMac 2011 refresh, but I'm troubled by the news that there are no SATA 3 connections. There's lots of confusion on Mac Rumors and [OWC blogged that there is no SATA 3](http://blog.macsales.com/10002-2011-imacs-no-sata-6gbs-yes-to-multiple-drives).

I was wondering if anyone has an iMac 2011 and can confirm that there is in fact no SATA 3 controller. I'm trying to determine if I should get a Vertex 3 or just stick with the Vertex 2. No SATA 3 controller would mean you wouldn't get any benefit from the Vertex 3. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We're starting to see some more clarification. The new iMacs come with the Intel Z68 chipset, http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/11/05/04/apples_new_thunderbolt_imacs_include_unreleased_intel_z68_chipset.html. Wikipedia says they have 2 6Gb/s ports and 4 3Gb/s ports. Hope there's more clarification how to use the 6Gb/s ports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that there is SATA 3 on board, it just wasn't enabled until 4 May 2011. The Other World Computing [blog](http://blog.macsales.com/10050-firmware-update-enables-6gbs-in-2011-imacs) has the details:

> While [iMac EFI Update 1.6](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1380) is described
>   as including “fixes that improve
>   performance and stability for
>   Thunderbolt,” it would also seem that
>   an unadvertised benefit is that it
>   also unlocks the full 6Gb/s, SATA 3.0
>   capabilities of two of the internal
>   drive bays.
>
> Unfortunately, the optical bay remains
>   at 3Gb/s.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a 2011 iMac, however you can trust the statement from OWC that you linked in your question.

They bought one, took it apart and unequivocally state that there is NO SATA 3 support.

Since they sell the Vertex 3 and the industry is moving towards SATA 3, it would not be in their commercial interest to make this statement were it not true.

Comment: Although this may well be true, it seems a really odd design move to leave off SATA 3 support.

Comment: I totally agree.

Comment: I’m not surprised that the iMac, which is a consumer machine, doesn’t have a SATA 3 controller. And even if it did, I can’t see it making a noticeable difference.

Comment: @Arthur While I could figure out what you meant in your comment, could you please use the standard lowercase-b for bits and uppercase-B for bytes? That way your second sentence is: "SATA 2 tops out at 3Gb/s which is 375MB/s". You clearly know what you're talking about, it's just hard to understand your comment without pulling out my calculator.

Comment: Edit: thanks @CajunLuke, good catch :). With the new Vertex 3 there'd be a huge difference. SATA 2 tops out at 3Gb/s which is 375MB/s. The Vertex 3 rates at aorund 550MB/s read/write, you'd be losing out on 175MB/s. SATA 3 tops out at 6Gb/s which is 750MB/s, giving you plenty of bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst there may be no SATA3 controller on board there is nothing to stop a SATA3 to Thunderbolt interface appearing in the future.

The lack of SATA3 on the new iMacs is not stopping me from buying one. Thunderbolt will provide all the expansion opportunities I need.